# How can I reset default 'root' user behavior on MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql

I am happy with the new MySQL 5.7 'root' user behavior. It allows only the linux root user on localhost to log in to MySQL as the MySQL root user.

I recently imported my old users table and it wrote over this change, now anyone can login as root on localhost with a password.

How can I restore the default MySQL 5.7 root user settings?

Please read the question carefully, as a lot of this functionality has changed from 5.5 to 5.7 and it is easy to answer this question backwards.

Comment: Presumably, this is done by setting the root user's authentication to use [`auth_socket`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/5.7/en/socket-authentication-plugin.html) but without a stock 5.7 server handy to say for sure, I hesitate to suggest specific changes.

Comment: Check your `mysql.user` table and `drop user` every `'root'@'someotherhost'` that is not `'root'@'localhost'`. (You can check `mysql.proxies_priv` too, but i think you just have root users with other hosts than localhost in `mysql.user`).

Comment: Solarflare - unfortunately not: ```mysql> select user, host from mysql.user where user="root";
+------+-----------+
| user | host      |
+------+-----------+
| root | localhost |
+------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this worked. See the answer posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem:**

The `auth_socket` module needs manually installed and enabled on the `root` user if you write over the 5.7 changes by importing your old `MySQL 5.5` database and user table.

**Solution:**

For users we want to still use `mysql_native_password`, the default. For `root`, we want to use `auth_socket`.

```
install plugin auth_socket soname 'auth_socket.so';
use mysql; update user set plugin='mysql_native_password';
update mysql.user set plugin = 'auth_socket' where User='root';
flush privileges;
```

If you do it in the wrong order (add `root`'s `auth_socket` column before installing the plugin), then you will be unable to load mysql since the plugin won't perform authentication. To start and run mysql in safe mode use this:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-table &
sudo mysql -u root -p -h localhost
```

These fixes were performed when importing a full database and user table from `MySQL 5.5` to `MySQL 5.7`, migrating from `Ubuntu 14.04` to `Ubuntu 16.04`.

**Tools:**

See Plugins: `show plugins \g`

Show auth_socket on root user:  `select auth_socket from mysql.user where user='root';`