# MySQL can't login as root on localhost even with sudo

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I can login as root on my localhost with blank password by doing:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

I would like to do this from Python with `PyMySQL`:

```
try:
    sql_conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root',
                           password='')
except:
    print('exception')
```

But I'm getting an exception even when I run my Python script as `root` or with `sudo`. How can I fix this (security is not a concern, isolated test environment).

Comment: This is the root user of your database, not the root user of your system.

Comment: if your mysql is 5.7.x or above ... try create a mysql user refer : https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/71

Comment: I would assume you are using `auth_socket` for your root user (try to specify a wrong (=any) password in your first command, you will still be able to login). You can change the (mysql) root account to use a normal password (so basically do the opposite of what is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39968082/how-can-i-reset-default-root-user-behavior-on-mysql-5-7)), or use a different user.

Comment: try 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  import pymysql
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='ServerIP', port=3306, user='remoteMe', passwd='mypassword', db='myDB')
```